# Can we control the HTML5 application cache?

Tags: angularjs, html, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I'm trying to develop a Angularjs Offline application for that I'm making use of application cache to cache all the resources. To implement this we need to include all the files in the cache.manifest file include that file in the html

My app.cache File:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
app.cache
index.html
app/app.js

NETWORK:
*

SETTINGS:
prefer-online

# hash: 23567ecbf082c4c3ccc008701719ab3b089ff8043b7ef5d1c11e5af003eb6250
```

Index.html

```
<html ng-app="myapp" manifest="app.cache">
 ....
</html>
```

This is how I'm trying to cache files let. but this starts caching the resources upon page load.

Can we cache the resources when we want to, say when a button is clicked?